# wxPython: User Input display of the calculator

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to Python and this is my very first attempt to built my very own Calculator application using wxPython.

```
import wx

########################################################################
class PyCalc(wx.Frame):
    """
    Python Calculator using wxPython
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Py Calculator",
                          size=(320,240)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        button1 = wx.Button(panel, label="1")
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button1.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button2 = wx.Button(panel, label="2")
        button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button2.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button3 = wx.Button(panel, label="3")
        button3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button3.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button4 = wx.Button(panel, label="4")
        button4.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button4.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button5 = wx.Button(panel, label="5")
        button5.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button5.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button6 = wx.Button(panel, label="6")
        button6.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button6.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button7 = wx.Button(panel, label="7")
        button7.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button7.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button8 = wx.Button(panel, label="8")
        button8.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button8.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button9 = wx.Button(panel, label="9")
        button9.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button9.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button10 = wx.Button(panel, label="10")
        button10.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button10.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))

        sizer = wx.GridSizer(rows = 3, cols=3, hgap =5,vgap =5) 
        sizer.Add(button1)
        sizer.Add(button2)
        sizer.Add(button3)
        sizer.Add(button4)
        sizer.Add(button5)
        sizer.Add(button6)
        sizer.Add(button7)
        sizer.Add(button8)
        sizer.Add(button9)
        sizer.Add(button10)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event, buttonLabel):
        """"""
        print "You pressed the %s button!" % buttonLabel

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = PyCalc().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

My question is what should I use for that display box in the calculator which displays what the user types in? What is in in WxPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wx.StaticText`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StaticText-class.html) seems appropriate for this case.

```
self.display = wx.StaticText(panel, label='0')
sizer.Add(self.display)
```

You can change the text using `SetLabel` method or `Label` attribute:

```
self.display.SetLabel('calculated_value')
# or
self.display.Label = 'calculated_value'
```